# Issue setting up Karma / Jasmine with Angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/testing-angular-with-karma) and [here](http://www.tuesdaydeveloper.com/2013/06/angularjs-testing-with-karma-and-jasmine/) for setting up Karma & Jasmine for testing with my Angular project, but keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'http://localhost:9876' of undefined
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:44

Any idea what this issue is? I'm new to using Karma & Jasmine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try some better references ~ https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: Did you ever work out what the issue was?  I've suddenly got this issue too on a project where it was previously working.

Comment: Follow this link for instaruction for setting karma/jasmine http://samyakwebdev.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 and using latest Karma v0.13.16 (as of today). I installed `karma` and `karma-chrome-launcher` and got the same error. To fix it, I just installed `karma-jasmine`. I guess it pulls in a newer fixed version

```
npm install karma-jasmine -g
```